# Android Firebase not working for flutter web

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, web, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working on my app I added a firebase Android backend tho I need the app to work on both Android and web, When running the app on an android emulator everythin works just fine but When I run it on a web (Google Chrome) the code excutes without giving any errors but the chrome window is empty and dont have anything on it.
The UI worked just fine on both web and android before adding firebase and yes I have added a web app on firestore.
thanks for the help

Comment: Did you add the web app on Firebase and added the files that firebase give you for the web ?

Comment: yes I did add those

Comment: Can you add us, some code with your main.dart and the configuration file for the web ?